# Calculation of residue at infinity and problem from Complex Variables, Mark J. Ablowitz

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, infinity

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Suppose we know that everywhere outside the circle $C_R$, radius $R$ centered at the origin, $f(z),g(z)$ are analytic with $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z) = C_1$ and $\lim_{z \to \infty} zg(z) = C_2$ where $C_i$ are constant. Show: $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{C_R}g(z)e^{f(z)} = C_2e^{C_1}$$

I know this problem involves residue at infinity. But I have issues trying to calculate it. By the well-known formula we get:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{C_R}g(z)e^{f(z)}dz = -Res_{z=\infty}g(z)e^f(z) = Res_{z=0}\frac{g(1/z)e^f(1/z)}{z^2}$$ since the residue at infinity of $f$ is defined by

$$Res_{z=\infty}f(z) = - Res_{z=0}\frac{1}{z^2}f(1/z)$$

So I'm basically having issues calculating said residue.

Comment: There is no other information on $g$? Taking $g=he^{-f}$ then the left hand side can be anything you want, independent on $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: Yes! My bad, I just changed it

Comment: Ok. Since $\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)=C_1$, then $f$ is analytic at $\infty$ (by defining $f(\infty)=C_1$). Likewise $h(z)=f(1/z)$ will be analytic at $z=0$ with $h(0)=C_1$. By Riemann's theorem. The same argument tells that $g(1/z)/(1/z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$. Therefore, $\frac{1}{z}\frac{g(1/z)}{1/z}\exp(f(1/z))$ has a pole of order $1$ at $0$. Its residue is the limit of $z\cdot \left(\frac{1}{z}\frac{g(1/z)}{1/z}\exp(f(1/z))\right)$ at $z=0$. That is $C_2e^{C_1}$.